# Notation Question: Let $E/M$ be an elliptic curve and $\lambda$ an endomorphism, what is $M(E[\lambda])$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, notation, elliptic-curves

In [a paper on elliptic curves](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2016-85-299/S0025-5718-2015-03001-4/S0025-5718-2015-03001-4.pdf) I see the following notation used in section $4$: let $E/M$ be an elliptic curve over a field $M$ with CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $E[\lambda]$ by the kernel of the endomorphism given by $\lambda\in \mathcal{O}_K$.

**What does $M(E[\lambda])$ stand for?**

I assumed it was something simple but became confused when results like the following were stated in the paper (and made to seem immediate): $k(E[\lambda])=k\Leftrightarrow E[\lambda]\subset E(k)$. It doesn't seem like this should be immediate given the naive definition.

The notation was also used in the context of a single point $P$ on an elliptic curve $E$, simply $M(P)$. Is this simply the $M$-algebra generated by $E[\lambda]$ in some respect, and if so how does $k(E[\lambda])=k\Leftrightarrow E[\lambda]\subset E(k)$ hold?

Comment: $k(E[\lambda])$ is the smallest extension of $k$ over which all points of $E[\lambda]$ are defined. So if $k(E[\lambda])=k$, then every point of $E[\lambda]$ is defined over $k$, i.e., $E[\lambda]\subset E(k)$, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$([\lambda])$ is the smallest extension of $$ over which all points of $[\lambda]$ are defined. So if $([\lambda])=$, then every point of $[\lambda]$ is defined over $$, i.e., $[\lambda]⊂()$, and vice versa.